# Cancel Button on ASP.NET MVC Causes table to empty using Updated Tab

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a bit of a weird issue, currently, I have a mocked page with some partials and a tab menu, however, when I click on the cancel button to return to the page, one tab works great but the other when I try it goes back to the page but all the data is lost in the table.

This is what I have:

**Tabs**

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "viewwriteramendments" &&
             controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewWriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { songid = fullAccountCode})' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Original">Old Song Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "updatedwriteramendments" &&
             controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("UpdatedWriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { songid = fullAccountCode})' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Original">Updated Song Details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The tab marked **Original Works**

Main View Page, I have one for Original and one for Updated:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    @* DOM ready? *@
    $(function () {
        addTableStylingScripts();

        @* Pagination Async Partial Handling *@
        $(document).on("click",
            "#indexPager a",
            function() {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled') || $(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
                    return false;
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("href"),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                        addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        $(document).on("change",
            "#pageSizeSelector",
            function() {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: selectedValue,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                        addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                    }
                });
            });

        @* Sorting Async Partial Handling *@
        $(document).on("click",
            "#tableHeader a",
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("href"),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                        addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        @* cancel *@
        $(document)
            .on("click",
                "#js_CancelForm",
                function(e)
                {
                    var uri = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("WriterAmendments", "SongsManagement", new
                               {
                                   page = Model.PagingInfo.Page,
                                   take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                                   sortBy = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName,
                                   sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                               }))';

                    window.location = uri;
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
    });
</script>
}

@section additionalStyles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/plugins/select2/css/core.css">
}

@section modal {

}
<article class="row">
    <h1 class="pageTitle artistHeader fw200 mb30 mt10">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("_ViewWriterAmendmentsTabMenu", Model)
    </div>

    <div class="formContainer">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewWriterAmendments",
        "SongsManagement", FormMethod.Post,
        new { id = "js_ViewWriterAmendments", role = "form", @class = "theme-primary form-horizontal" }))
        {
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.Partial("_ViewWriterAmendmentsDetails", Model)
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 tableContainer">
                @Html.Partial("_ViewWriterAmendmentsList", Model)
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary review-btns" id="js_CancelForm" value="Cancel" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger review-btns" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reject Song" id="js_Reject" value="Reject" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning review-btns" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verify & Dont Send" id="js_Verify_DontSend" value="Verify & Dont Send" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success review-btns" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verify & Send Song" id="js_Verify_Send" value="Verify & Send" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</article>
```

Both use exactly the same razor and markup, however when on the Update Tabs page and you click cancel it goes back to the previous page, but the data in the table is lost.

This is the Controller:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Writer Amendments
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="songud">The accountcode.</param>
        /// <param name="page">The page.<
        /// /param>
        /// <param name="take">The take.</param>
        /// <param name="sortBy">The sort by.</param>
        /// <param name="sortAsc">if set to <c>true</c> [sort asc].</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("WriterAmendments/ViewWriterAmendments")]
        [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
        [ActionName("ViewWriterAmendments")]
        public ActionResult ViewWriterAmendments(int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                                string sortBy = "CreatedDate", bool sortAsc = true)
        {
            // init
            ViewBag.TenantCatalogues = null;
            var model = new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsViewModel();
            // Get the paging and sorting parameters from the model (if supplied), else use acceptable defaults.
            var skip = (page * take) - take;
            var songs = GetWriters(skip, take, sortBy, sortAsc);
            var songsTotalCount = GetWriters(0, int.MaxValue, string.Empty, true).ToList().Count;

            model.PagingInfo = new ViewModels.PagingModel
            {
                Page = page,
                Take = take,
                SortAscending = sortAsc,
                SortPropertyName = sortBy,
                Total = songsTotalCount,
                PipedFilter = string.Empty
            };
            model.FirstName = "First Name";
            model.MiddleName = "Middle Name";
            model.LastName = "Last Name";
            model.IsProMember = true;
            model.Society = "PRS";
            model.CaeIpiNumber = "123456789";
            model.Songs = songs;


            // AJAX?
            if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return PartialView("_ViewWriterAmendmentsList", model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel> GetWriters(int skip, int take, string fieldToSort = "CreatedDate", bool ascending = true)
        {
            var songs = new List<ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel>
                {
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },

            };

            if (ascending)
            {
                return songs.OrderBy(s => s.CreatedDate).Skip(skip).Take(take);
            }
            else
            {
                return songs.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate).Skip(skip).Take(take);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// New Songs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uniqueworkid">The accountcode.</param>
        /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
        /// <param name="take">The take.</param>
        /// <param name="sortBy">The sort by.</param>
        /// <param name="sortAsc">if set to <c>true</c> [sort asc].</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("UpdatedWriterAmendments")]
        [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
        [ActionName("UpdatedWriterAmendments")]
        public ActionResult UpdatedAmendments(int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                                string sortBy = "Membership", bool sortAsc = true)
        {
            // init
            ViewBag.TenantCatalogues = null;
            var model = new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsViewModel();
            // Get the paging and sorting parameters from the model (if supplied), else use acceptable defaults.
            var skip = (page * take) - take;
            var songs = GetUpdatedWriters(skip, take, sortBy, sortAsc);
            var songsTotalCount = GetUpdatedWriters(0, int.MaxValue, string.Empty, true).ToList().Count;

            model.PagingInfo = new ViewModels.PagingModel
            {
                Page = page,
                Take = take,
                SortAscending = sortAsc,
                SortPropertyName = sortBy,
                Total = songsTotalCount,
                PipedFilter = string.Empty
            };
            model.FirstName = "First Name";
            model.MiddleName = "Middle Name";
            model.LastName = "Last Name";
            model.IsProMember = true;
            model.Society = "PRS";
            model.CaeIpiNumber = "123456789";
            model.Songs = songs;


            // AJAX?
            if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return PartialView("_ViewWriterAmendmentsList", model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel> GetUpdatedWriters(int skip, int take, string fieldToSort = "CreatedDate", bool ascending = true)
        {
            var songs = new List<ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel>
                {
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },
                    new ViewModels.ViewWriterAmendmentsDataViewModel
                    {

                        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        RowVersion = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        IsDeleted = false,

                        SongId = "SEN00000000001S",
                        SongTitle = "Song Title",
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Writers = 1,
                        Recordings = 2,
                    },

            };

            if (ascending)
            {
                return songs.OrderBy(s => s.CreatedDate).Skip(skip).Take(take);
            }
            else
            {
                return songs.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedDate).Skip(skip).Take(take);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Try putting a debugger in the partial view and then click on cancel and check if the model is empty!

Comment: You cant use a Debugger on the Partial, I have tried it and it does not allow you to do so. The model is not empty because I can see the data from it on the screen. I will add the debugger on the Controller as that seems more logical.

Comment: Thats odd, you should be able to debug in partial view. Restart visual studio, try putting debug points at different lines in partial view.